# How to edit the notification email that admin receive when anyone register in the Wordpress MULTISITE

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications, mu

I am working on a wordpress MU site.I am using domain mapping plugin.Now I want to modify the content of the notification email that admin receives when anyone register on the sites.I have searched in the internet and found function in pluggable.php in wp-includes folder of the wp installation.But event if i am overriding the function the mail content is still the same.
Here is the code:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

    $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Testing message" . "\r\n";

    @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

    if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
        return;

    $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('Adios!');

    wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

}
```

}

Any help will be appriciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to override this function in your theme `functions.php`.
You have to do it in a plugin, since plugin will be loaded before `pluggable.php`.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion.But i have checked this link already and made a plugin as suggested but no luck :-(

Comment: Search for wp_new_user_notification in your wordpress files, there's maybe another plugin which already override this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook into the wp_mail hook.

Inside your hook function, you can check for the content and can try to change it.

Comment: Yes I have made a small plugin which overwrites the function.But the changes i have made is not reelecting in the email content.And the interesting fact is for testing purpose i have delete the function from pluggable.php file but then also the notification email is coming and no error is showing.

Comment: I guess there is some problem in your hook function. Can you post the code to that?

Comment: I have found this plugin but this is not working for me also.remove_action( 'wpmu_new_user', 'newuser_notify_siteadmin' );
add_action( 'wpmu_new_user', 'newuser_notify_siteadmin_enhanced' );

function newuser_notify_siteadmin_enhanced( $user_id ) {
 /* some mailing functions*/
}